# Hardware accelerated mplayer does not render movie in Fedora 26

Tags: ffmpeg, fedora, codec, mplayer

I bought a GPU for my Linux system just to be able to play movies without any glitches and issues of integrated graphics and get rid of messages like your "system is too slow to ...". Then I configured Mplayer, to use HW acceleration. So I googled following settings to be added to ~/.mplayer/config

```
#vo=vdpau

[vo.vdpau]
vc=ffmpeg12vdpau,ffwmv3vdpau,ffvc1vdpau,ffh264vdpau,ffodivxvdpau
```

vo=vdpau is commented because *some* movies cannot be played; just blank screen is "rendered".

```
Selected video codec: [ffh264vdpau] vfm: ffmpeg (FFmpeg H.264 (VDPAU))
```

If I run this without -vo vdpau, I see, that different codec is used and video is rendered:

```
Selected video codec: [ffh264] vfm: ffmpeg (FFmpeg H.264)
```

Any reason why there's no video in first execution of mplayer? How to use HW acceleration for this movie? What's wrong with FFmpeg H.264 (VDPAU)??

I'm actually not interested in vdpau itself, I just want accelerated, working playback; vdpau is just the first way I find how to do that. And sometimes it even works.

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer for Mplayer, but the
[ffmpeg HWAccelIntro documentation](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/HWAccelIntro)
gives this table for hardware support:

[image]

As can be seen, VDPAU support is very limited and is only implemented on Linux
with a NVIDIA (but who knows what card model and which driver).

So you might just consider it to be non-implemented.

Comment: ok, so the GPU is "MSI GeForce GTX 1050 Ti". What would be correct usage how to get accelerated movie playback? I'm actually not interested in vdpau itself, I just want accelerated, working playback

Comment: What is your operating system?

Comment: linux. The reported behavior is taken from "a little older" fedora 26. To be reinstalled when I have time to do so.

Comment: Suggest you try to replicate the problem using VLC https://www.videolan.org/vlc/